# Using Django model forms + form wizard + Crispy - Does not proceed to second step

Tags: python, django, forms, wizard, django-crispy-forms

I am fairly new to forms in django.

My issue is I have a few very large models that I have to break up into a series of smaller forms for the users to fill out.

So I've been playing around with crispy forms and yesterday after watching Mike Hibberts tutorial ( Python Django tutorial 19 - Using the Form Wizard ) on youtube I wanted to see if I could make this work with a crispy form.

Everything seems to render ok to me, however when I press submit the form seems to be validated but does not proceed to step 2.

Am I doing this completely wrong??

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

---

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import StrictButton

from models import ProcessSheet

class EnterData(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EnterData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'save'))
        """
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'sheet_id',
            'sheet_title',
            'part_name',
            ButtonHolder('save', css_class='btn-warning'),
        )
        # You can dynamically adjust your layout
        """

    class Meta:
        model = ProcessSheet
        fields = "__all__" 

class Sheet1(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "sheet 1 init!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        super(Sheet1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'sheet_id',
            'sheet_title',
            'part_name',
        )

    class Meta:
        model = ProcessSheet
        fields = "__all__" 

class Sheet2(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sheet2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'cooling',
            'nozzle',
            'zone_5',
        )  
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessSheet
        fields = "__all__"
```

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
from process_forms.models import ProcessSheet
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView 

import logging
logr = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from forms import EnterData

# Create your views here.
def SheetSelect(request):
    logr.debug( "IM IN SELECT!!!!!!!!!!!!" )
    print "IM IN SELECT!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    form = EnterData(request.POST or None)
    log_data_message = "Please Enter Some Data"

    if form.is_valid():

        data = form.cleaned_data

        if not ProcessSheet.objects.filter(sheet_id=data['sheet_id']):

            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            form = EnterData()
            log_data_message = "Data Entered Ok!"
        else:
            log_data_message = "Sheet ID already exists!"

    sheets = ProcessSheet.objects.all()    
    return render_to_response('PS14.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def SheetFocus(request, sheet_id=0):
    sheet = ProcessSheet.objects.get(id=sheet_id)    
    return render_to_response('PS24.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

class SheetWizard(SessionWizardView ):
    logr.debug( "IM IN WIZARD!!!!!!!!!!!!" )
    template_name = "sheet_form.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        logr.debug(  "IM IN DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!" )
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render_to_response('done.html', {'form_data': form_data})

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    logr.debug(  "DONE PROCESS FORM DATA!!!!!!!!!!!!" )
    return form_data
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from process_forms.forms import Sheet1, Sheet2
from process_forms.views import SheetWizard

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^all/', 'process_forms.views.SheetSelect'),
    url(r'^get/(?P<sheet_id>\d+)/', 'process_forms.views.SheetFocus'),
    url(r'^entry/', SheetWizard.as_view([Sheet1,Sheet2])), 
)
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.
class ProcessSheet(models.Model):

    ejector_confirmation_on = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    number_of_cavities      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,validators=[
                                MaxValueValidator(100),
                                MinValueValidator(1)
                            ])
    date                    = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    shift                   = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,validators=[
                                MaxValueValidator(4),
                                MinValueValidator(1)
                            ])

    sheet_desc              = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment                 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    sheet_id                = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=False,null=True)
    sheet_title             = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    part_number             = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=False,null=True)
    part_name               = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    machine_no              = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    special_notes           = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True, null=True)
    end_of_arm_tool_number  = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    program_picker_robot    = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    nozzle_tip_size         = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    k_cut                   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hydraulic_unit_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    valve_gate              = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    colorant                = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    reasons_for_changes     = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    finger_print            = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    initial                 = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)    

    V1                      = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    V2                      = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    V3                      = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    V4                      = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    V5                      = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    position_pressure       = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True) 
    pack_1                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pack_2                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pack1                   = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pack2                   = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    shot_size               = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    back_1                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    screw_speed             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cushion_in_inches       = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    injection_time          = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cycle_time              = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cooling                 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    hot_sprue_1             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    nozzle                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_1_barrel           = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_2_barrel           = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_3_barrel           = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    mold                    = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    dryer                   = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_1                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_2                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_3                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_4                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_5                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_6                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_7                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_8                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_9                  = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_10                 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_11                 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    zone_12                 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    flowmeter_reading       = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def Meta():
        managed = True
```

---

sheet_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<H1> This is the entry form </H1>
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<br>

{{log_data_message}}        

<form action="/sheets/entry/" method="post">

{{ wizard.management_form }}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% crispy wizard.form %}




{% if wizard.steps.prev %}

<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">"first step"</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">"prev step"</button>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

{% endblock %}

{% block links %}

{% for sheet in sheets %}
    <a HREF="/sheets/get/{{ sheet.id }}">{{sheet.sheet_title}}</a>
    <br>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

<br>
```

Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future i think ive solved my issue.
took a little while for me to figure it out but my persistent tinkering payed off.
sorry im not going into detail about what i had to change, but im sure most of you can see the changes from the code i posted. the forms look great! the session wizard works as expected! and all seems to be ok. best of luck everyone!!

Class from forms.py

```
class Sheet1(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Sheet1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['machine_no'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_site_choices())
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    #self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
    #self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        HTML("{% include \"progress_bar_min.html\" with value=\"1\" %}"),
        HTML("{% include \"form_head_information.html\" with value=\""+str(args)+"\" %}"),
        TabHolder(
            Tab(
                'Sheet Information',
                    PrependedText('sheet_id', 'Django-'),
                    Alert(content='<strong>Automatically Generated ID!</strong> Just so you know.', css_class="alert-warning alert-dismissible"),
                    'sheet_title',
                    'part_name',
                ),
            Tab(
                'Press Location',
                    'machine_no',
                    'sheet_desc',
                ),
            Tab(
                'Comments',
                    Alert(content='<strong>Help Us Improve!</strong> Please leave lots of comments.', css_class="alert-info alert-dismissible"),
                    'comment',
                ),
        ),
        ButtonHolder(
            Submit('Save', 'Save', css_class='btn-info'),
            Submit('wizard_goto_step', '0'),
            Submit('wizard_goto_step', '1'),
            Submit('wizard_goto_step', '2'),
        ),
    )
    query = ProcessSheet.objects.latest('id').sheet_id
    self.fields['sheet_id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['sheet_id'].initial = query+'-'+str(time.time())
    self.fields['sheet_id'].label = "ID For This Sheet"
    self.fields['sheet_title'].label = "Enter A Title For This Sheet"
    self.fields['part_name'].label = "Enter The Part Number"
class Meta:
    model = ProcessSheet
    fields =(
        'sheet_id',
        'sheet_title',
        'part_name',
        'machine_no',
        'comment',
        'sheet_desc',
            )
```

sheet_form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<H1> This is the entry form {{views_context_var}}</H1>
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<br>

<form action="/sheets/entry/" method="post">
{{ wizard.management_form }}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% crispy wizard.form %}

</form>

{% endblock %}

<br>
```

Comment: Haven't quite got through the full implementation but I'm taking this as an example. I will comment on what I find in an answer. Thank you for writing this.

Comment: Did you change anything to Sheet 2 or did you just use Sheet 1 as an example? What happened to TestSheet1 and TestSheet2? Was it because you have your ModelForm?

Comment: Took your code but the buttons are not dynamic, but you made them static. Is there are reason?

Comment: Are you referring to the page navigation buttons or the submission button?

Comment: Page navigation. I got it to work similar to yours but now I'm at the point on how to get the button to show "NEXT:" rather than the value in a crispy form. Thoughts?

Comment: @Logic1 How would you insert a **prev** button to go back to the previous page?

Comment: @Logic1 I used `HTML()` instead but will try to find a better way: `HTML('<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}" class="btn btn-light">Prev</button>')`

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solved a little bit of the issue, or maybe just got lucky.

In forms.py where the meta() fields = '__ all __'

needs to be changed to reflect the fields of interest, I used the variable Sheet1_layout and Sheet2_layout. After that the wizard seems proceed to the next step.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import StrictButton

from models import ProcessSheet

Sheet1_layout = (
    'sheet_id',
    'sheet_title',
    'part_name',
    )          
class Sheet1(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print "sheet 1 init!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        super(Sheet1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(Sheet1_layout,
                                    ButtonHolder('save', css_class='btn-warning'),
                                    )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'Save'))
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessSheet
        fields = Sheet1_layout


Sheet2_layout = (
    'cooling',
    'nozzle',
    'zone_5',
    )        
class Sheet2(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Sheet2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
        # It builds a default layout with all its fields
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'text-center col-lg-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(Sheet2_layout,
                                    ButtonHolder('finish', css_class='btn-warning'),
                                    )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save', 'Finish'))
    class Meta:
        model = ProcessSheet
        fields = Sheet2_layout

class TestSheet1(forms.Form):
    sheet_id = forms.CharField(max_length=16)

class TestSheet2(forms.Form):
    hello = forms.CharField(max_length=16)
```